# How to do CVS commit using java code

Tags: java, commit, cvs

I need to commit a file into CVS repository using java code.

My requirement is, When a submit button is clicked, I need to receive the call to java method and then commit a file to CVS repository using Java code in the background without using any GUI tools.

I know the below items.

- Branch to commit.
- Name and path of the file to Commit.
- CVS repo url.
- CVS Username and password.

How can I use the above details to connect to CVS server and then do the commit?

Comment: "without using GUI tools" is unclear... You just said when the submit button is clicked... Anyways, if you know how to do this all from the command line, then you can use Java to run the same command.

Comment: @cricket_007 I do not know how to do from command line . Can you help me with the commands.

Comment: I don't know the commands myself... What do you mean that you don't know the commands? How would you commit your files **outside** of Java?

Comment: @cricket_007 I use eclipse to commit. using cvs repository plugin.

Comment: I'd suggest you either find some Java library capable of doing CVS operations, or [learn how the command line does it](http://www.cs.umb.edu/~srevilak/cvs.html), then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find below the solution which worked for me.
Its pretty straightforward and easy.

```
   ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(
            "cmd.exe", "/c", "cd D:/CVS_REPO/ && dir && cvs checkout  && cd project_folder && cvs commit -m \"Admin Tool\"");
        builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
        Process p = builder.start();
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while (true) {
            line = r.readLine();
            if (line == null) { break; }
            System.out.println(line);
        }
```